# 500 - Internal Server Error, after migrate windows server 2012 R2 to windows server 2016

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have migrated Windows server 2012 R2 to Windows server 2016 (IIS 10). After migrated, all the link that connected to server is working normally, but except 1 link that not working. It shown **500-Internal server error**. It's weird when I remote to my virtual machine for windows server 2016, the error is gone. But if I disconnect it, the error still can not solve.

I really don't know why the Windows server 2012 work normally, but after migrate to the new version why it doesn't work? and both of them using virtual machine.

Error after click the link

[image]

Comment: Very likely that you forgot some dependencies or configuration, but FRT should lead you to the culprit, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Besides, I suggest you could also disable the custom error message to let us know what has happened. More details about how to disable the custom error message, you could refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/815166/how-to-troubleshoot-asp-net-web-applications).

Comment: Another place to look for the full error message is in "Event Viewer"->"Windows Logs"->"Application" on the server.